# Plotly: setting same color order for same elements in 2 graphs

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using Plotly in Javascript to make some graphs.

I want to make 2 pie charts showing the distribution of a sale by A) units B) value.

I get the plots ok, but as the share of each category changes from one plot to the other, colors also change, making it less intuitive to compare.

What I want is to keep the colors related to the X values. Any clue?

```
        grafico_categoria = document.getElementById('grafico_categoria');
        categorias = {{ arr_productos_categoria|safe }}
        yvalue = []
        labels = []
        $.each(categorias, function(index, value) {
                yvalue.push(value['uds']);
                labels.push(value['productos__categoria_producto__categoria_producto']);
        });
        value_1 = {values: yvalue,
              labels: labels,
              type: 'pie',
              hoverinfo: 'none',
              textinfo: "label+percent",
              textposition: "outside",
              automargin: true
              };
         data = [value_1,];
         var layout = {
              height: 300,
              width: 550,
              margin: {
                l: 10,
                r: 10,
                b: 10,
                t: 10,
                pad: 4
              },
          showlegend: false,
          paper_bgcolor: 'white',
          plot_bgcolor: 'white',
        };
        Plotly.newPlot(grafico_categoria, data, layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking for this, the solution is to set "Sort" to false, this way the chart always keeps the original dataset order.

```
value_1 = {values: yvalue,
           sort: false,
           labels: labels,
           type: 'pie',
           hoverinfo: 'none',
           textinfo: "label+percent",
           textposition: "outside",
           automargin: true
           };
```